# creating log and error files in nzsql

Tags: logging, nzsql

i am using nzsql query to run a query , i was able to create the required data file, but even after creating data file, but  log and error file created were of size zero.

**SCRIPT USED:**

```
nzsql -Atv  dt="'2015-12-31'"  -v a=0  -v "condition=(PROD.USC_CODE IN 
(27311,27312,27318,27390,37340,38900,48300,53584,61130,82110,82120,82130,82140,8
2180,82200,82210,82211,82212,82220,82230,82240,82900,86210) OR (PROD.USC_CODE 
=78120 AND PROD.PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION = 'RIBAVIRIN' ))" -f /development/df2/dfr
/sql/adhoc/sriram/test_1.sql>/development/df2/dfr/sql/adhoc/sriram/gen.log 
2>/development/df2/dfr/sql/adhoc/sriram/gen.err -o /development/df2/data01
/sriram/test_data.dat
```

please let me know what could be the problem for not filling in log and error files.

Answer (score 0):

You are using "-o" option with nzsql that sends query output to an output file. You need to use "-O" (uppercase o) to send query output or error to a file.

Thanks,
Sanjit